# How to export Bing Maps layers to Pdf with Arcmap - and get appropriate resolution?

Tags: arcmap, bing-maps, pdf

I've got a GP service that creates a new mxd, adds Bing Layers to it, zooms to a particular extent, then exports a pdf.  Sometimes (when the network is slow, I suspect) the resulting pdf has a mixture of tiles from different resolutions.  Is there some way to set a timeout that causes arcmap to wait longer for tiles to be received for the scale being plotted?

**Update**

[image]

On closer examination, the timeout may be a red herring.  I notice that IActiveViewEvents.AfterDraw fires many times as the pdf is being generated.  This suggests that the map is being drawn in chunks.  Looking at the pdf, I see that the low res areas extend all the way across the map, so I guess the chunks are horizontal strips.  Only a few of the strips are lo res.  Assuming the chunks are drawn from top to bottom, it seems like if it were a timeout issue then only the top strip would show low res.  Notice how the low res strips are in the middle though.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the same thing myself and agree that it probably has to do with a slower internet connection.  It is definitely a pain and frustrating.  The only advice I can give is when this happens is to clear out the cache in the base layer by right-clicking it in the Table of Contents in ArcMap, by going to the Cache tab and clearing it.  This will cause the the Bing tiles to reload again and hopefully this time in a more uniform way.  I'm not sure this will help your scenario  but it has helped me.

Comment: Thanks wilbev, on the Cache tab I've checked "don't cache any data locally".  I've submitted this to Esri support, will post their response once I get it.

Comment: This seems like a pretty significant problem.  I hope esri will address this.